# Reload kafka producer's bootstrap.server config on broker restart

Tags: apache-kafka

We have a kafka broker setup on internal cloud. We find actual url using zookeeper and provide in bootstrap.server config.
Now the problem is when the broker restarts the internal cloud restarts it on dynamically allotted machine with new host port. Now the host port which i have initially given in producer config is not valid.

Question is how can i reload this config without restart.

Note: i know this is a bad design to host broker where it can restart in a different machine, but this is how it is right now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the domain name instead of ip in bootstrap.server config.

Comment: But we have lot of kafka brokers in our domain, we need our app to listen to only our speific broker, cant i get a callback or notification when the broker is not available?

Comment: "Question is how can i reload this config without restart."
We can't reload this config without restart.

If you restart brokers one by one, producers can work well.
And when you restart producers, you must modify bootstrap.servers config now.
You have only one broker ?

Comment: We have 5 brokers but even if one broker which is leader restarts than how will it connect? Is there a way to get notification?

Comment: If only one of five brokers restarts, you need do nothing. And the cluster will work well.
Kafka bootstrap.servers can be configed multiple ip+ports. But as long as one of them works, kafka cluster can work well(producers can push messages to Kafka correctly).